# pd.DataFrame is showing only the last result of a loop

Tags: python, pandas

**Code:**

```
  for i in df["Date"].unique():
    a = df[(df['Date']==i)  & (df['Billable']=="Yes")]["Duration"].sum()
    b = df[(df['Date']==i)  & (df['Billable']=="Yes")]["Duration"].mean()
    print(i,a,b)
```

The following code returns this output:

```
Jan, 2019 10

Aug, 2019 20

Feb, 2019, 40

June, 2019 30
```

---

Which is what I need so then I converted it into a data frame like:

```
d = {
        "col1" : a,
        "col2" : b,
    }
    data_test = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[i])
    data_test
```

But this only gives me the last month as a result:

```
June, 2019 30
```

Is there a way that the data frame (data_test) return every month and not just the last one?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I strongly recommend reading the Pandas docs, it's unlikely that an explicit loop is actually necessary here. What are the possible values in the `'Billable'` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Eric's answer, the pandas way to do this is:

```
import numpy as np

df[df['Billable'] == 'Yes'].groupby('Date').agg({'Duration': [np.sum, np.mean]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the values of 'a' and 'b' each time you loop. Try appending them and building a new dataframe. Something like this would be one way to do it using your method:

```
a_list = []
b_list = []

  for i in df["Date"].unique():
    a = df[(df['Date']==i)  & (df['Billable']=="Yes")]["Duration"].sum()
    b = df[(df['Date']==i)  & (df['Billable']=="Yes")]["Duration"].mean()
    print(i,a,b)

    a_list.append(a)
    b_list.append(b)


d = {"col1" : a_list,  "col2" : b_list}
data_test = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks! Do you know how can I change the name of the data frame index so instead of having numbers from 1 to 12 I can see the actual months names?